# Set default charset on a database created with FBManager

Tags: java, firebird, jaybird

I've created a database using jaybirds' class `FBManager`, but I can't find a way to specify a `default charset` for it (defaults as `NONE`).

Am I missing something? Is it possible to define it after the database was created?

This is the snippet used to create it

```
FBManager fbm = new FBManager();
fbm.start();
fbm.createDatabase("./fb.fdb", "user", "password");
fbm.stop();
```

---

**This feature is now available in Jaybird version 3.0.6 and higher. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726114/5542561) for more details.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>You aren't missing anything: this feature is indeed absent from `FBManager`. Consider filing an improvement ticket on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC</s>

This feature is now available in [Jaybird 3.0.6](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.6/release_notes.html#changes-in-jaybird-3.0.6) and higher. The method [`FBManager.setDefaultCharacterSet`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.x/docs/org/firebirdsql/management/FBManager.html#setDefaultCharacterSet-java.lang.String-) was added to set the default character set.

For earlier versions of Jaybird, as a workaround, you will need to alter the default character set after creating the database.

For Firebird 3 and higher you can do this by using

```
ALTER DATABASE SET DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8
```

See also [Alter the Default Character Set](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-ddl-enhance.html#rnfb30-ddl-alterdftcharset) in the Firebird 3 release notes.

For Firebird 2.5 and earlier you'll need to modify the system tables directly (this is no longer supported in Firebird 3):

```
UPDATE RDB$DATABASE SET RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME = 'UTF8'
```

Replace `UTF8` with your intended default character set if it is a different character set.

Either statement must be executed as the database owner or as user SYSDBA.

Be aware, changing the default character set only has effect on columns created **after** the new default has been set. Existing (var)char columns will retain their old character set.

Disclaimer: I maintain the Jaybird JDBC driver for Firebird.

Comment: The workaround will do it. Just filled in a [ticket](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-541). Thanks.

Comment: @Peba Thanks for that. If it is quick and easy to do, I'll do it in Jaybird 4 and maybe even backport it to Jaybird 3.